# Existence of continuous selection for metric projection

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, metric-spaces, selection-principles

Let $(X,d)$ be a separable complete [geodesic metric space](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Geodesic_metric_space) and let $K$ be a compact (non-empty) subset of $X$.  Without assuming things like linearity, the convexity of $K$, and locally convexity, under what conditions can we guarantee that there is a continuous selection for the *metric projection problem:*
$$
\operatorname{argmin}_{k \in K} d^2(x,k)?
$$

Comment: This rules out many natural conditions -- will you give an example of a condition of the form that you're looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the trouble, I'm only familiar with the conditions I ruled out or those for Micheal's Selection theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $argmin$ is not continuous. Even on the real line, if I take $K$ to be two distinct points, say $K=\{-1,1\}$, then $argmin_{k\in K} d^2(x,k)$ is not continuous. This is why convexity is so important. Without assuming convexity, little is guaranteed in this case.